# How do I make a Android Service where I can pass information to it when it starts?

Tags: android

I wanna start an android service but I need to pass some info to it before it starts how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few approaches you could take.

Take a look at http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/04/simple-complete-app-widget-part-1.html for an example of adding a value to the Intent extras, which is then received by an IntentService in onHandleIntent.

Another approach would be to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which makes it very easy to provide an arbitrary data structure.

For more ideas, take a look at how [Jeff Sharkey's android-sky app](http://code.google.com/p/android-sky/) handles threading.

Comment: Thanks so an intentservice is what I should use so I can pass extras around hmmm thanks dude :) AsyncTask is nice but I need this service to run in the background

Comment: That's where AsyncTasks run.  You don't have to publish results to the UI thread.